# Why does the index in which.max() not match the value of index when I type in the given vector[which.max()]?

Tags: r

Hello I have just started learning R a few weeks ago. Was practicing an exercise where it stated commute times were tracked for one week (just weekdays) and below are the recorded times in min:

```
commute <- c(17, 16, 20, 24, 18)
```

I named the vector to its corresponding weekday:

```
names(commute) <- c("M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F")
```

The exercise states:
Using diff(), find the day with the greatest change from the previous day.

So I found the day with greatest change to be Friday by writing

```
which.max(abs(diff(commute)))
```

But why does it give me Thursday when I type the following?

```
commute[which.max(abs(diff(commute)))]
```

How would I be able to adjust this code to print out "F" rather than giving me the index value?

Comment: I think the names might just be misleading. Look at the output of `diff(commute)`. In that case it drops the first name, but that might not be how you are interpreting the change. Maybe just `names(which.max(abs(diff(commute))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` returns length 1 less than the original vector.

```
length(commute)
#[1] 5
length(diff(commute))
#[1] 4
```

So add `+ 1` to `which.max` index to get correct value.

```
commute[which.max(abs(diff(commute))) + 1]
# F 
#18
```

Alternatively, if you only want the name ("F") you can extract `names` from `which.max` output.

```
names(which.max(abs(diff(commute))))
#[1] "F"
```